# Can you set LayoutParams for an ImageView with a specific XML resource, if so, how?

Tags: android, imageview

For example I have written this tag for my ImageView:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/battery" />
```

I want to put it in a file somewhere (I don't know where I should do that), so I can:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(theXmlResourceIWantToUse)
```

There are many answers related to this but almost all of them are about how to set those parameters in REAL TIME, I don't want that and I don't need that, how do I do it with an XML, if it is possible?

Comment: do you want to place the in a separate file like a style which you could reuse

Comment: Yes, it would be preferable that way. But if you must place it inside some other layout, it's OK. As long as I can reuse it.

Comment: just place your ImageView,TextView,etc in a layout as you wish and import that xml to places where you need it  <include layout="@layout/xml_layout_name" /> (Do you want me to make this as an ansewer)

Answer (score 0):

In `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="CustomStyle">
   <item name="android:layout_width">100dp</item>
   <item name="android:layout_height">100dp</item>
   <item name="android:adjustViewBounds">true</item>/> 
</style>
```

Then:

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageView9"
     style="@style/CustomStyle"
     app:srcCompat="@drawable/battery" />
```

Is that what you meant?

Comment: You seem to have solved a part of the puzzle,  where should I leave the <ImageView> xml information, so I can use it as a resource to construct a LayoutParams object, then use IT for the ImageView, using "setLayoutParams"?

Comment: I am not sure you can do that to be honest. Perhaps consider making a class that contains a static member that is your LayoutParams object so you only have to declare it once, then just use `MyClass.params`. 

This is because the options available in xml and in LayoutParams are not necessarily the same.

Comment: In other words, either I do everything statically with an XML file, or dynamically with zero XML involvement?

Comment: You can do both at the same time but I don't know if you can make a layoutpsrams object from xml directly.

Comment: Hah, too bad then. TY anyway.